# apache mod_rewrite help: writing an exception to a rewrite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a site with this existing rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so that it captures all URLs and translates them to this query.

How can I precede this with something that will make an exception for URLs of the form

```
http://www.example.com/services/{anything}
```

e.g. any URL that refers to something in a `/services` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/services
```

If you are putting this into .htaccess, you might need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !services
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !services/
```

Comment: is /services a regexp? do I need the ^ in front of it?

Comment: Quite possibly it is.  Try it with and without a ^ and see which works best.  Also see the full docs on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html which is for apache 2.0 and probably hasn't changed recently.

Comment: 12 years later & still a sound working solution! I did not need to use a ^.